# Update specific index of array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, backend, crud

I would like to update the shipping property in my MongoDb (CRUD).
Shipping is an **array** property that contains object[index]. How to update the specific object such as index1 or index2.

[This show the shipping property that contains two objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeQQH.png)

If I want to update Object only at index 1 on the providerName, how can I do that

```
exports.updateShpping = (req, res) => {
const {shipping} = req.body;
Shop.findOne({ _id: req.shop._id },  (err, shop) => {

    if (!shipping) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'shipping is required'
        });
    } else {
        shop.shipping.push(shipping) ;
    }

    shop.save((err, addShipping) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Shipping ADD ERROR', err);
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Shipping add failed'
            });
        }
        res.json(addShipping);
    });
});exports.updateShpping = (req, res) => {
const {shipping} = req.body;
Shop.findOne({ _id: req.shop._id },  (err, shop) => {

    if (!shipping) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            error: 'shipping is required'
        });
    } else {
        shop.shipping.push(shipping) ;
    }

    shop.save((err, addShipping) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Shipping ADD ERROR', err);
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: 'Shipping add failed'
            });
        }
        res.json(addShipping);
    });
});
```

};

Comment: Please include the contents of the image as proper text within the post.

Comment: Do you really wanted to update object at index `1` every time irrespective of what object it is ?